# ¿Existen los equivalentes a los archivos .NDF y .LDF de SqlServer en todos los Gestores de Base de Datos?

Tags: mysql

Solo después de aprender algo de SqlServer vi un poco de PostgreSql y me doy con la sorpresa que ahí se usaba 'workspace'. Pero luego al echarle un ojo a Mysql no encuentro como indicar una ubicación en mi PC dónde quiero que se cree mi base de datos. Una rápida googleada no me ha dado ningún resultado y acudo a este lugar mientras sigo googleando. Espero alguien me ayude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La ubicación depende del sistema operativo y, dentro del sistema operativo, la ubicación de la data depende también del motor. Si sigues un wizard de instalación, da igual dónde elijas poner tu data, porque el archivo de configuración le dirá cómo acceder a ella.

La estructura interna de archivos es distinta para cada motor. Como bien has dicho, **la estructura interna de SQL Server** consiste en mantener las tablas (y triggers, y funciones) en un `.MDF` (que es el primary data file), un `.NDF` (secondary data file) y `.LDF` (log data file).

Dicho esto, te voy a contar un poco cómo se estructuran los archivos físicos de los motores con que he trabajado. *Esta no es una respuesta completa y ninguna respuesta a esta pregunta va a ser la correcta*, pero **si más personas responden sobre los motores que conocen**, el conjunto de respuestas como un todo debiera ser información complementaria.

### En MySQL

(que en linux corre en `/var/lib/mysql`)

- el concepto de "base de datos" es igual al concepto de schema en otros motores. No hay, como en otros motores, una jerarquía donde una base de datos contenga N esquemas.
- cada schema está representado por un directorio, y dentro de ese directorio hay N archivos.
- Cuando se usa el motor MyISAM, por cada tabla hay tres archivos (uno de estructura, otro de datos, otro de índices).
- Cuando se usa el motor InnoDB, hay dos manera de almacenar la data.

  - Si usas el setting `innodb_file_per_table` se comporta como `MyISAM` manteniendo un archivo `.frm` y un `.idb` por cada tabla.
  - Sin ese setting, que antes ni siquiera existía, cada schema mantiene una colección de archivos `ibdata` numerados que en realidad son un solo archivo separado en volúmenes. Y dentro de ibdata están todas las tablas InnoDB y sus atributos.

MySQL soporta el uso de tablespaces indicando el atributo [DATA DIRECTORY al momento de crear la tabla](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-placing.html).

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INT PRIMARY KEY) DATA DIRECTORY = '/alternative/directory';
```

Utilizar esta configuración provoca, por debajo, que dentro del directorio indicado se cree un árbol que replica los la estructura de subdirectorios (uno por schema) del directorio de data principal de MySQL, pero conteniendo únicamente las tablas que hayan sido creadas en ese tablespace.

Dentro del directorio principal, en el subdirectorio del respectivo schema, MySQL crea links simbólicos para cada tabla que reside en otro tablespace

Las tablas que se crean en un tablespace no pueden moverse a otro con un simple ALTER TABLE. Hay que darse el trabajo de recrear la tabla copiando los contenidos.

### En postgreSQL

(que en linux se aloja en `/var/lib/postgresql`), la estructura es un poco más compleja. El archivo de configuración permite que pongas la data  donde se te de la gana, e internamente crea links simbólicos adonde corresponda. Básicamente, hay un subdirectorio `base` que contiene a su vez un subdirectorio por cada base de datos en el servidor (un servidor puede correr N bases).

```
- PG_DATA
  - base
    - base1
    - base2
    - base3
```

Pero además, en postgres, cada `tablespace` se mapea a un directorio físico de la máquina, así que puedes tener distintos tablespace en distintos discos físicos, distintas particiones, distintos sistemas de archivos. Para mantener esto bajo control, hay también un subdirectorio `pg_tblspc` con links simbólicos a cada tablespace.

Dada una base de datos y un tablespace, las tablas propiamente tales son archivos de la forma

```
base/12345/6789
```

Donde `base` es el subdirectorio que indiqué antes, `12345` es el `oid` de la base de datos, y `6789` es el `oid` de la tabla. Todo esto equivale a decir que mirando el directorio de instalación de postgres no tienes cómo saber cómo diablos está organizada la base ni qué contiene.

De todos modos, sólo como dato referencial, si quisieras saber a qué archivo corresponde una tabla, eso se puede averiguar haciendo:

```
select pg_relation_filepath('mitabla');
```

Y eso se usa en el inusual caso en que haya un problema físico que obligue a operar directamente con el archivo.

[Los tablespaces de postgres son entidades como lo son las tablas, índices, schemas, etc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html). La única diferencia es que representan una ubicación física en el sistema de archivos. Entidades como índices y tablas pueden moverse libremente de un tablespace a otro a medida que quieras tunear rendimiento o te vayas quedando corto de espacio.

### En SQLite

En SQLite, un solo archivo es autosuficiente, y contiene la lógica, el motor y la base de datos todo en uno. La idea es que en aplicaciones sencillas (como una app móvil) puedas tener una base de datos local y autocontenida sin apelar a ningún servicio ni programa del sistema. Todo funciona en un solo archivo y ese archivo no tiene una extensión definida. Por convención se usa la extensión `.sqlite` para que alguien que lo encuentre en una aplicación sepa qué es ese archivo.

SQLite no soporta tablespaces. Como es autocontenido en un archivo, no tendría sentido romper esa integridad creando más archivos.

### En MongoDB

MongoDB se instala en `/var/lib/mongodb` y su estructura más básica es mantener todas las bases de datos en un solo archivo, pero todo es configurable.

En MongoDB, similar a MySQL, no existe una jerarquía separada para base de datos y esquema. Las colecciones residen en una base de datos y esa es toda la jerarquía que hay.

- El directorio que aloja los datos está en el archivo de configuración y puedes ponerlo donde quieras
- El archivo de datos puede dividirse en X volúmenes de Y tamaño, que se van añadiendo con el tiempo.
- Se puede configurar para que cada base de datos ocupe un subdirectorio distinto
- Dentro de ese subdirectorio, de nuevo dependiendo de tu configuración, hay un archivo monolítico o N volúmenes

Este layout, que era el único existente hasta MongoDB 2.x, tenía el problema que al eliminar una tabla o índice no recuperabas el espacio en disco de vuelta sino hasta que optimizabas toda la base de datos. Como este motor se ofrece para albergar colecciones masivas de documentos, la optimización de una base de datos y recreación de los índices puede durar horas, y el espacio desaprovechado puede ser masivo.

Desde la versión 3, se incorporó a MongoDB el motor WiredTiger, el cual tiene una estructura más clásica

- Cada base de datos es un subdirectorio
- Cada colección de cada base de datos equivale a un archivo en su subdirectorio
- Cada índice de cada colección de una base de datos equivale a un archivo en el mismo subdirectorio

Lo anterior significa que si una colección tiene 5 índices, entonces genera 6 archivos en su subdirectorio. Todos estos archivos tienen extensión `.wt`.

MongoDB no contempla el concepto de tablespace. [Su documentación sobre el storage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/storage/) se limita a enumerar los motores de almacenamiento.

De todos modos, siempre es posible emular un tablespace montando un subdirectorio en otra unidad (en linux esto es trivial).

### En Oracle

Lamentablemente nunca he instalado Oracle localmente. Sólo lo he usado como cliente mientras que el DBA mantenía la instalación celosamente custodiada en un rack de blade servers que corrían Solaris. Eran otros tiempos.

### TLDR; (Versión ultra resumida)

- Casi la totalidad de los motores de bases de datos permiten que elijas en qué subdirectorio irá la data independiente de dónde corren los ejecutables del servicio de BBDD.
- Muchos motores te permiten elegir entre mantener archivos monolíticos, separar cada base de datos o schema en un subdirectorio, y en ese subdirectorio separar cada tabla en su(s) propio(s) archivo(s).

La gracia de mantener distintas bases de datos o distintos schemas en distintos subdirectorios, es que se vuelve muy simple montar cada subdirectorio en discos separados, y de esa manera multiplicar la velocidad de transferencia fisica de una consulta.

Comment: Muy buena info. Pero yendo directamente a mi duda estoy entendiendo que no puedo crear base de datos personalizados, como en SqlServer o un workspace como en Postgresql, en todos los gestores.

A lo que me refiero es que más allá de un simple 'create database mibase' en SqlServer me permite indicar un directorio. Pero parece que no aplica a todos los gestores. Que si no me equivoco  el directorio se establece en el momento de la instalación. ¿Estoy bien?

Comment: En MongoDB tengo entendido que no se puede. En MySQL sí se puede, voy a añadir esa  información